# Any way to be able to install the same ClickOnce app from two different locations?

Tags: .net, assemblies, clickonce

We build the application once, and then deploy it to multiple sites.  I can install it from any of the deployed servers, but I cannot have it installed from multiple at the same time.  I understand that this is a limitation of ClickOnce.  Is there any way to trick ClickOnce into allowing this to work?  Or any site-specific post-processing that I can do to the assemblies?  I doubt the latter since the ClickOnce manifests were signed at compilation.

Comment: Also, does anyone know the reason for this limitation?  Why can't the client machine treat AppX from SiteA as completely unrelated to AppX from SiteB?

Comment: Because they're full of signatures that say they're the same?

Comment: Are you signing your deployment?  If so, did you buy a code signing cert or are you just using the Visual Studio generated one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this. The reason is that the installation URL is part of the identity of the deployment, and is included in the security features. This ensures that someone doesn't hijack your application and have your users install their updates instead of yours, and install malware.

Comment: I am able to host the application at any URL (as long as I run it from the .application file and not the setup.exe.

Comment: Yes, you can host it anywhere, but you can't install it from one URL and get updates from another one. You can even deploy it to several servers, but people can't change from one server to another.

Comment: I don't need them to be able to change from one server to another.  I would just like to be able to install from two places and each installation gets it's updates from the place it was installed from.  Obviously it's not permitted, but I still see no reason why they chose to prohibit it.

Comment: You should be able to do that. Two choices. 1: You can build it once to each server with the installation URL for that deployment set to that server, then send the "right" URL to each customer. I would do that if it's on the public internet, or if you want to be really secure.

Comment: If it's on a company intranet, you can deploy it w/o a deployment URL. In the Options dialog under Manifest, there is an option for "exclude deployment URL". If you check that, you can then put both deployments out on the servers. When the user installs it, it will set the URL on his machine to the one he used to install it, and check that URL for updates. I definitely would NOT do this if it's on the public internet, it would be a major security risk.

Comment: How does someone hijack a ClickOnce deployment in a way that a fixed installation URL prevents?  Don't they need access to the PC to begin with or somehow convince the user to click their installation URL and trust their Authenticode certificate?

Answer (score 1):

There is code snippet available at http://geekswithblogs.net/thibbard/articles/70844.aspx which achieves manual Clickonce deployment and management. You can change the code as per your convenience. Manual updating gives control to developer to update Clickonce deployment at will.

Comment: Yes, I'm already updating via code.  But this doesn't help the situation.

Comment: You can change the updating URL dynamically without effecting the deployed manifest.